# create two Virtual Host for single IP

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

Sorry, my question may be duplicated. But, I've already read several stack similar, but none have solved my problem.
I want to create two VirtualHost (to have multiple DocumentRoot) in my server apache2.
This is my configuration (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default):

```
ServerName jlcj.goforward.com
 <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin test@localhostxxx
      DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony/ws1/web 
      <Directory />
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
      </Directory>
     <Directory /var/www/symfony/ws1/web>
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All 
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>


Alias /pages    "/var/www/pages"

 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin test@localhostxxx
     DocumentRoot /var/www/mtbe_test
    <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mtbe_test>
         Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All 
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
   </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>
```

Then, I have tried to bind to another port but it not listening, like this:

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
ServerAdmin test@localhostxxx
DocumentRoot /var/www/mtbe_test
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/mtbe_test>
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /mtbe_test    "/var/www/mtbe_test"
  </VirtualHost>
```

Help please, what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up different Virtual Hosts.
For every virtual host you can set a diffrent document root.

The important thing here is set up diffrent ServerName's. So if you have a domain called: `domain.com` and you would like to have a diffrent document root for `subdomain.domain.com` you need to build two virtual hosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /www/htdocs/
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /www/subdomain/
</VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration you have the document roots `/www/htdocs` for `www.domain.com` and `/www/subdomain/` for `subdomain.domain.com`

If you would like to add another system folder to your document root, you could use a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

Comment: +1 but, Is it possible to put the same name on both VirtualHost (eg :www.domain.com)?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? You could add another system folder to your documentroot with a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimal config to perform what you need:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```